# Azure function not appearing under functions after deploying

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We followed the below and used func tool as well as azure cli to deploy a python function. No matter what even after the dpleoyment is successful, the function does not appear.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash%2Cbrowser

We were able to find the zip package under the path site-packages via kudu. The weird part is that deployment of the python function works fine via Visual studio code.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Got it resolved and was silly. Posting here in case if it helps someone. func deploy had to be run from one folder ahead of the actual functions folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what Vaishnav meant with "one folder ahead". But my issue was that I hadn't opened the directory containg all of my Azure functions, but its parent directory instead. When I directly opened the directory that contains all my Azure functions, it suddenly showed up again.